# Set the dimensions of image captured in android

Tags: android, image, android-camera

In my application, I have an activity where we can capture the image from camera on button click using intent and set the captured image into imageview. Its working absolutely fine.

But now i want the image in  specific dimensions. For example, in my case the dimensions of my image view is 150dp * 150dp. So i want that the dimensions of image captured by camera should also always be 150dp * 150dp in order to fit perfectly. How can i do this?

Here's my main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button btnTackPic;
    TextView tvHasCamera, tvHasCameraApp;
    ImageView ivThumbnailPhoto;
    Bitmap bitMap;
    static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get reference to views
        tvHasCamera = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHasCamera);
        tvHasCameraApp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHasCameraApp);
        btnTackPic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTakePic);
        ivThumbnailPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivThumbnailPhoto);

        // Does your device have a camera?
        if(hasCamera()){
            tvHasCamera.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
            tvHasCamera.setText("You have Camera");
        }

        // Do you have Camera Apps?
        if(hasDefualtCameraApp(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)){
            tvHasCameraApp.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
            tvHasCameraApp.setText("You have Camera Apps");
        }

        // add onclick listener to the button
        btnTackPic.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    // on button "btnTackPic" is clicked
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        // create intent with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE action 
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        //Edit to save picture      
      File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "my-photo.jpg"); 
      Uri photoPath = Uri.fromFile(file);
      intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoPath);

        // start camera activity
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);

    }

    // The Android Camera application encodes the photo in the return Intent delivered to onActivityResult() 
    // as a small Bitmap in the extras, under the key "data"
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode== RESULT_OK && intent != null){
            // get bundle
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            // get 
            bitMap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

            ivThumbnailPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitMap);

        }
    }

    // method to check you have a Camera
    private boolean hasCamera(){
        return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
    }

    // method to check you have Camera Apps
    private boolean hasDefualtCameraApp(String action){
        final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        return list.size() > 0;

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **scale your Bitmap** like the following code:

```
Bitmap originalBitmap = <the original bitmap>;
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
    originalBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, false);
```

Hence according to your requirement,the resized bitmap must be generated as:

```
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
    bitMap, 150,150, false);
```

Note:Here 150 is measured in pixels,so you have to calculate 150dp to pixel and then place it.